# How to show image in table using mysql command line

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, blob

I have tried to show photo in MySQL command line, but always unable to do. Although I can retrieve photo using *JDBC*.

I am beginner to learn *JDBC* using MySQL, so, please help me by giving answer.mysql code are given below

> **`create database image;`
>
>        `use image;`
>
>        `create table imgtable(photo,BLOB);`
>
>        `insert into imgtable(photo) values(LOAD_FILE('D:\\pic.png'));`
>
>       `select *from imgtable`;**

I cannot find storage photo in *imgtable*, only show garbage. But why it occur like this, actually is it not possible to show in table. Please suggest a way.

Thank you.

Comment: Differentiate between a command line interface and a GUI interface. If you fire a query on that table from MySQL command line (terminal), you will end up only with a (huge) binary stream. You just cannot do it. You always need a GUI tool for that.

Comment: you can use sqlyog GUI

Comment: thanks @Tiny ,it can also use MySQL workbench? Which is most preferable to me between sqlyog GUI and MySQL workbench GUI as a beginner.

Comment: Do it! There is also a facility to view and upload files directly in a BLOB field (needless to say something about specialization like `LONGBLOG`, `MIDIUMBLOB`, `TINYBLOB`), if you are not merely playing around with DDL, DML for pure learning purposes :)

Comment: thanks @Tiny,OK now sqlyog use

Comment: @Tiny firstly sorted an image that i can view the image from sqlyog. but when i have stored mp3 file,why i cannot show/play the mp3 file in sqlyog.

Comment: Despite the fact that playing a multimedia file requires an appropriate media player which may not be supported by the GUI tool - sqlyog, I choose to remain silent about it because I am not well-familiar with sqlyog.

Answer (score 1):

Blob data types in mysql store the information in encoded form. Hence you can only see the result in garbage form which is not actually garbage but your image in encoded form.